# Write to a file in Android library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm writing an Android library and would like to write to assets/myfile.txt.  After doing some reading it appears assets is read only at run time.  So I've decided to attempt at writing to the internal storage via openFileOutput("myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

The problem here being that openFileOutput() is not found.  I've created a library in Eclipse using the wizard.  Inside of my project I have the following Interface and Class.

```
public interface MyClass {
  public void writeToFile(String key, String value) throws IOException;
}

public class MyClassImpl {
  @Override
  public void writeToFile(String key, String value) throws IOException {
    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    // ...REST OF METHOD TO WRITE TO THIS FILE...
  }
}
```

I'm targeting the latest API, and when I write the above code in Eclipse I get the following error

> The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type
>   ClientImpl

Do I need to extend some class here to implement openFileOutput() in my interface/class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here being that openFileOutput() is not found

[`openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Your `Activity`, for example, is a subclass of `Context`.

> Do I need to extend some class here to implement openFileOutput() in my interface/class?

You need to call `openFileOutput()` on a valid instance of a `Context`, such as your `Activity`. For example, you can pass one into your `writeToFile()` method as a parameter.